# Error in varimp (R party package) when conditional = TRUE

Tags: r, party

I am trying to calculate variable importance for a random forest built using the `cforest` function in the `party` package. I would like to run varimp with conditional set to `TRUE`, but I get an error message when I do so. The error reads:

> Error in if (node[[5]][[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3omlBvhP_vBNU9XSEljRjIyNk0/view?usp=sharing)] == variableID) cp <- node[[5]][[3]] :
>   argument is of length zero

Varimp run with the default setting `conditional = FALSE` works just fine.

Regarding the data set, all variables are categorical. The response variable is Glottal (yes/no), and there are seven predictors. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3omlBvhP_vBNU9XSEljRjIyNk0/view?usp=sharing) to the data, and here is the code I am using:

```
library(party)

glottal.df <-read.csv("~glottal_data.csv", header=T)

glottal.df$Instance <- factor(glottal.df$Instance)

data.controls <- cforest_unbiased(ntree = 500, mtry = 2)
set.seed(45)

glottal.cf <- cforest(Glottal ~ Stress + Boundary + Context + Instance + Region + Target + Speaker, data = glottal.df, controls = data.controls)

# this gives me an error
glottal.cf.varimp.true <- varimp(glottal.cf, conditional = TRUE)

# this works
glottal.cf.varimp.false <- varimp(glottal.cf)
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? It is not a problem with any specific variable as the problem persists even if I remove a variable, create a new forest and try to recalculate varimp, and there are no missing values in the data set. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be working with party 1.2.4:

```
> glottal.cf.varimp.true
       Stress      Boundary       Context
 0.0003412322  0.2405971564  0.0122369668
     Instance        Region        Target
-0.0043507109  0.0044360190 -0.0011469194
      Speaker
 0.0384834123
> packageVersion('party')
[1] ‘1.2.4’
> R.version
               _
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          4.3
year           2017
month          11
day            30
svn rev        73796
language       R
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: While I understand and agree with the sentiment, this is a 2-year old question with zero answers. I landed here wondering if this was still an issue. It's not.

In all likelihood, the *actual* answer to "why am I getting this error" is a software bug in an old version of the package. Unfortunately, the question author has not provided sufficient information to reproduce the problem (I tried). Yes, one could reasonably argue that my answer should be a comment. Alternately, my response does answer the question: "you're getting this error because you're using an old version of the package".